# program to implement vector in java

Tags: java, vector

I am a beginner in Java and I have to implement vector in java by using these methods `addElement(), elementAt(), removeElement(), size()` and I don't know how I tried to write the code of `addElement` first and I am getting this error :

[image]

Please I really need help with this

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Vector;

class Vectimplement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.add("element_1");
        v.add("element_2");
        v.add("element_3");
        v.addElement("New Element");
        System.out.println("Elements in Vector :");

        for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(v.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing it if you're simply using the already existing `java.util.Vector` class?

Comment: he probably meant "using" and not implementing

Comment: I think that's a warning (or note, apparently), not an error. It's good that you stop and reflect on them too though :)

Comment: kunal is right i meant using not implements(like in interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After supressing warnings I was able to run program successfully :

```
package test;

import java.util.Vector;

class Vectimplement {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector v = new Vector();
    v.add("element_1");
    v.add("element_2");
    v.add("element_3");
    v.addElement("New Element");
    System.out.println("Elements in Vector :");
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(v.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

Console Output :

```
element_1
element_2
element_3
New Element
```

These warnings are generated because after Java6(or maybe 7) it was required to explicitly provide the "type" of Objects to be stored in containers. Hence, the best practice is to use :

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<>();
```

Comment: Note : `@SupressWarnings()` should be avoided at all possible cost. use only when u want to run at any cost. The recommended way is to use `generics` as suggested by @ilyai's answer

Answer (score 3):

Use generics to specify the type of objects you're going to put into the collection.

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector is a pre define class you can use it's method my creating it's object as follow,

To add values in vector use object.add() methods,

following are some methos:

public class Vectorexapp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector v=new Vector();
        v.add(10);
        v.add(20);
        v.add("HELLO");
        v.add(40.5);

        System.out.println("first element:"+v.firstElement());

        System.out.println("last element:"+v.lastElement());

        System.out.println("Values of vector:"+v);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector to add element at specified position:

public class Vectorexapp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector v=new Vector();
        v.add(0,10);
        v.add(1,20);
        v.add(2,"HELLO");
        v.add(3,40.5);

        System.out.println("Value at index 2:" +v.get(1));
        System.out.println("Values of vector:"+v);
        v.clear();
         System.out.println("After clear vector values:"+v);
    }

}

output:
Value at index 2:20
Values of vector:[10, 20, HELLO, 40.5]
After clear vector values:[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add values by accepting it from user:
public class Vectorexapp {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         int a,b;
         String s;
         double c;
         System.out.println("Enter 2 integer values, 1 string and 1 float value:");
         a=sc.nextInt();
         b=sc.nextInt();
         s=sc.next();
         c=sc.nextDouble();

        Vector v=new Vector();
        v.add(0,a);
        v.add(1,b);
        v.add(2,s);
        v.add(3,c);
        System.out.println("vector values:"+v);
         System.out.println("vector size:"+v.size());
         System.out.println("Vector capacity:"+v.capacity());

    }

}

output:
Enter 2 integer values, 1 string and 1 float value:
60
40
abcd
50.6
vector values:[60, 40, abcd, 50.6]
vector size:4
Vector capacity:10
```